# Procedure about simplifying radicals

Tags: radicals

I have this:

$$\frac {(2n+1)^3-8n(n^2-1)}{\sqrt{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}}=\sqrt{\frac{144n^4+336n^3+220n^2+28n+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}}$$

What does this mean? What's the step by step procedure to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

$n=\sqrt{n^2}$ for any nonnegative real $n$, so $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{m}}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{m}}=\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{m}}.$$ Does this help?

Comment: This is the whole rule to get the result stated above?

Comment: It is, but you'll have to expand the polynomial expression to reach the right hand side's numerator.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You'll have to expand $(2n+1)^3-8n(n^2-1)$ and combine like terms to find $n$, then square the resulting expression to find $n^2$.